# how to fix error: object of type 'generator' has no len() -python

Tags: python, networking, cluster-analysis

I just want to do the community detection using Girvan Newman Algorithm, and the code was learned from a youtube video. However, when I run the same code, there comes an error

I have tried on Mac OS X python 2.7 terminal and python 3.7 by Jupyter both and the error are the same.

[image: the code I applied]

I expect the output to have two communities lists

Comment: convert it to a list? if it's large it will blow up your memory though

Comment: Please include your code directly here on StackOerflow.

Comment: And not as an image. It needs to be as text.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert to a list first to get the len:

```
l = len(list(c))
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But I cannot get the contents of two communities, the error is: AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'.